# jQuery filter() and closest()

Tags: jquery, filter, closest

I'm trying to learn how to use jQuery's closest() and filter() methods. closest() traverses up the DOM tree while filter() traverses down.

In the following code, after a user clicks the link, jQuery should search up the DOM until it finds the "row" class, search down until it finds the "test" class then return the text in that element. Why is console log printing blank instead of "Hello?"

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
 console.log( $(this).closest('.row').filter('.test').text() );
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="row">
   <td><span class="test">Hello</span>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><a class="button" href="#">Button 1</a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `</a>`.

Comment: Updated, but still not printing "Hello."

Comment: I think you got the basic idea for `closest()` but your understanding of `filter()` is incorrect.

Comment: Are you mixing up `.find()` and `.filter()`? `filter()` reduces a set of matched elements whereas `find()` traverses the dom

Comment: @empiric Well, that was it. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: You should not have updated your question's code with the solution. Now your question looks a bit ... hmmm.

Comment: ok, I changed it back to being wrong heheh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up `filter()` and `find()`

**`filter()`**

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector

This will not return anything because `closest('.row')` does not contain an element with `.test`

**`find()`**

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements

Searches for `.test` down the DOM starting at the element returned by `closest('.row')`

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).closest('.row').find('.test').text());
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td><span class="test">Hello</span>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><a class="button" href="#">Button 1</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When you really want to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) instead if `find()` you could do something like this:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
var text;
 $(this).closest('.row').filter(function(){
   text = $( ".test", this ).text();
   return $( ".test", this ).length === 1;
  });
  console.log(text);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td><span class="test">Hello</span>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><a class="button" href="#">Button 1</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I would not recommend this as it defies the purpose of having a dedicated function for that.

Answer (score 3):

So basically you misunderstood what `filter()` does. From what you say you're wanting to do you should use `find()` instead.

#### HTML

```
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td><span class="test">Hello</span>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><a class="button" href="#">Button 1</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).closest('.row').find('.test').text());
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81np68zh/) for you to play around.

#### EDIT:

To clarify here's what `filter()` does:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

So in you original code - your matched element is the `.row` element. You're trying to reduce that to elements that has `test` as a class as well.